# Call a java function every time I visit a website

Tags: java, web

Every time I visit a new website in a browser I would like to pass the URL I visited to a Java function that will be running in the background. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Java app is standalone from browser?

Comment: Unless you have a way to attach the Java application to the browser, or allow your Java application to log the keystrokes, and use it only if it forms a URL, I don't think it would be possible.

Comment: which browser do you want to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (Windows only). You can subscribe to events like HTTP requests, and respond in an appropriate way - calling the Java function in your example.

If you only want to respond to websites that you visit with the browser, you can check the user-agent HTTP header.